# Change IBM Worklight project path

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I need to create a Hybrid Worklight project but it needs to be physically inside another project.

The reason is that we are using an API that generates a project using grunt and the guide I got (company standards, practices, etc) says: Once the project is in Eclipse, create a `wl` folder and create the Worklight project inside of it.

When I create a new Worklight project in Eclipse it always goes to Eclipse's Workspace folder. How can I change this?

Thanks

Comment: What is your Worklight version? What are those company standards? are they written assuming they should even work with Worklight? What is this "project" generated by Grunt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot (at least, not in a standard/supported/known working way); a Worklight *project* contains Worklight *applications* but cannot contain other Worklight *projects*. Worklight *projects* are always contained directly within an Eclipse workspace (unless working with the CLI tools).

Based upon your clarifying comment, it seems that your containing "(general) project" is just another directory that contains a `wl` directory - not a real Eclipse project - that in turn contains your Worklight project. It seems you are creating the whole thing using the CLI tools.

In order to work with this project within Eclipse, you'll need to create a new Eclipse workspace elsewhere (the Eclipse workspace itself isn't particularly important and doesn't necessarily need to saved in source control). You can then use **File**->**Import**->**Existing Projects** into Workspace to import the Worklight project from the `wl` directory. You can either "Copy projects into workspace" (in which case you will end up with two copies), or leave that unticked, in which case your Eclipse workspace directory will just contain a reference to the original directory (I suspect you want the latter).

As a word of advice, generally you should try not to work with both Eclipse and the CLI tools at the same time. Although it may work, you will get conflicts with (for example) the embedded test server, and long term, you'll just cause confusion.

Comment: Actually is the other way around. The WL project needs to be inside another (general) project. The guide says: "Our API actually doesn't have the capability to create a WorkLight project. So you have to do that yourself. First, create a directory named wl. If you prefer CLI, you can run:

 mkdir wl

Create a new WorkLight project under wl directory in Eclipse. Make sure you name it <appName>_proj. Once that's done, add a new app and name it <appName>. You should see wl/<appName>_proj/apps/<appName> created."

Comment: Jose, OK, that makes more sense - however, my statement is still correct. When you refer to the "(general) project", you are not referring to an Eclipse-based project. From the CLI's perspective, your "(general) project" is just another directory. I'll modify my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** looks like Andrew says pretty much the same.

Using Eclipse, since what you see in the Project Explorer view is the workspace Eclipse uses, it makes sense to me that when you create a Worklight project in Eclipse, it will be located - in the filesystem - inside the workspace.

If you want to create your Worklight project elsewhere, you'll probably need to use the Worklight CLI tool. From a terminal, navigate to the location of the Grunt project and then, using the CLI commands,  generate a Worklight project in that location.